# Create API using Hibernate - Project Overview

Tags: java, hibernate

I wanted to check I was on the right track with my application.

I have started using hibernate under IntelliJ. It's created some entities based on my database schema and I have successfully managed to save to the database with some test code.

From here I plan to create a library for connecting to my database which can be used by web and mobile applications.

Am I right in thinking what I want to do is have a set of methods which expose the data via something like JSON i.e. something like getAllUserEntities() etc. which my application (frontend) can call.

I am kind of working alone so would appreciate some pointers on the best way to go about this.

In terms of the front end I was looking at the Play framework. Also possible I would try and use this libary from Android, which I know will need to access via HTTP.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I'd start by determining your specific requirements, based on what you actually need your software to do.